# ImapLib get gmail id mail(python)

Tags: python, email, gmail, imaplib

Sorry for my english. For example i have link like this

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?source=sync&tf=1&view=pt&th=1614fcf57d5cb6ec1&search=all
```

where `1614fcf57d5cb6ec1` it uuid message. By this link i can view pdf mail. For work with mail i use imaplib. I try get this uuid gmail message like this:

`mail.get('Message-id')`

but it give me id like this: `3CB8978E-60DD-41B1-AA2E-0685219513F3@happyplugs.com`

My question: Hav i can get id gmail message use imaplib?

UPD:

```
IMAP_SERVER = 'imap.gmail.com'
IMAP_PORT = '993'
IMAP_USE_SSL = True

 def __init__(self):
        print("MailBox __init__")
        self.user = '123@gmail.com'
        self.password = '123'
        if IMAP_USE_SSL:
            self.imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER, IMAP_PORT)
        else:
            self.imap = imaplib.IMAP4(IMAP_SERVER, IMAP_PORT)

    def __enter__(self):
        print("MailBox __enter__")
        self.imap.login(self.user, self.password)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.imap.close()
        self.imap.logout()

def get_google_id():
 self.imap.select('Inbox')
status, response = self.imap.search(None, 'ALL')

        if status == 'OK':
            items = response[0].split()
            for email_id in reversed(items):
                status, response = self.imap.fetch(email_id, "(RFC822)")
                if status == 'OK':
                    email_body = response[0][1]
                    mail = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)

                    id_mess = mail.get('Message-id') //this give me not gmail mail id
```

Comment: It's looking like you have extracted the contents of the SMTP `Message-Id:` header. Without seeing your code, we can't really know.

Comment: @tripleee thks for comment, i upd my question

Answer (score 1):

`imaplib` has a separate set of functions to operate on IMAP UIDs.

```
status, response = self.imap.uid('search', None, "ALL")
for uid in reversed(response[0].split()):
    status, response = self.imap.uid('fetch', uid, '(RFC822)')
```

Comment: thnks for answer. But how i can get GMAIL ID like this http://take.ms/EjIXY i want then generation link

Comment: By quick search I can't find a way that IMAP exposes the Gmail API identifier for a message. That doesn't mean it doesn't exist, but if that's your question, I'll delete this answer. ("uuid" is not a correct term either way. The API calls its identifier -- which is what I now assume you want -- the "id" and the IMAP identifier is the UID.)  There is an SMTP header field `X-Google-Smtp-Source` which might contain some undocumented information, but merely base64 decoding a sample didn't reveal anything useful.

Comment: Please also see https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions for additional fetch items, including a Gmail thread and persistent ids.

Comment: @Max You should post an answer based on that.

Comment: It'd be a link-only answer, and I don't have the time at the moment to flesh it out.  It's also not clear how to get the Gmail-ID and change it to a link; they're different encodings.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer then. I'm also a bit swamped at the moment but I'll try to update the answer tomorrow. The documentation in https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions#access_to_the_gmail_unique_message_id_x-gm-msgid looks fairly straightforward.